# Show All Color Variants on Collection page in Shopify using Blockshop Theme

Tags: collections, shopify, product, variants

I am using Blockshop theme in my Shopify website. I have different products will color variants. When I click on collection page I want to show all color variants of that products as separate products. Please help

Comment: How many color variants are there?

Comment: depends on product itself....few product have 2 color variats and few have 3

Comment: Use this `https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product` and `https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/variant` inside product `forloop` in the collection to get your required thing done.

Comment: Thanks Hymnz..i will get back once applying it.